# Mui's StaticTimePicker and Next JS server action

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I have a form I want to capture some data along with the time that the user selects. I've chosen StaticTimePicker from mui because I like the functionality.

Im trying to take advantage of NextJS's server action's. I know how to capture the information from the form data using the name property, however, im not sure how to capture it from the StaticTimePicker, if its even possible? I know that I can use the data from the onChange but then would I also send that info to the server action?

Thanks in advance for any help! Im new to server actions and like the idea of not having to create an api route :)

Here's my code below:

**Form**

```
"use client"

 <form action={addTimeEvent}>
          <div className="grid gap-4 mb-4 sm:grid-cols-2">
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="category"
                className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white"
              >
                Nap Type
              </label>
              <select
                id="category"
                name="napType"
                className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500"
              >
                <option defaultValue="" value="start_nap">
                  Start
                </option>
                <option value="end_nap">Stop</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <StaticTimePicker
                orientation="landscape"
                slotProps={{ actionBar: { actions: [] } }}
                onChange={(data) => {
                  console.log(data.$d, typeof data.$d, new Date(data.$d));
                }}
                value={dayjs()}
                name="napTime"

              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
            <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover-bg-primary-700 dark:focus-ring-primary-800"
              >
                Add Event
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

**server action function**

```
'use server'

import { prisma } from "@/app/lib/db";
import { NapOption } from "@prisma/client";
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

export const addTimeEvent = async (formData: FormData) => {

    const napTime = formData.get("eventTime")   <---- does just getting the name work?
    const napType = formData.get("napType")

    await prisma.nap.create({
        data: {
            event_type: napType as NapOption,
            event_timestamp: new Date (Date.now()) ,
            child_id: '123456' 

        }   
    })
    revalidatePath("/admin")
}
```

Comment: I did a workaround because StaticTimePicker probably does not have an input in the dom tree, you can just add one:  <input type="hidden" name="eventTime" value={YOUR_VALUE_SENT_TO_SERVER_ACTION_HERE} />